# Checkbox option to produce an SQL result

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox

what function should I use to obtain a "Y" if the checkbox has been selected or "N" if it has not. This is to add into a SQL statement?
I'm guessing it is an if/else but I can't figure it out.

Here is my checkboxes which some may be selected individually:

```
                        <label class="timetable-q">Data Projector</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="proj_check" name="proj_check" value="Y"/>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="proj_check" name="proj_check" value="N"/>
                        <label class="timetable-q">Whiteboard</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="white_check" name="white_check" value="Y"/>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="white_check" name="white_check" value="N"/>
                        <label class="timetable-q">OHP</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="ohp_check" name="ohp_check" value="Y"/>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="ohp_check" name="ohp_check" value="N"/>
                        <label class="timetable-q">Wheelchair Access</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="wheel_check" name="wheel_check" value="Y"/>    
                        <input type="checkbox" id="wheel_check" name="wheel_check" value="N"/>                                  
                        <label class="timetable-q">Lecture Capture</label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="cap_check" name="cap_check" value="Y"/>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="cap_check" name="cap_check" value="N"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="submit">
                        </p>
                        </form>
```

Here is my PHP:

```
<?php 
                        $numeroOption= $_POST['numero'];
                        $selectOption = $_POST['parkname'];
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM `ROOMS` WHERE `Capacity` < '$numeroOption' AND `Park` LIKE '$selectOption%'"; 
                        $result = mysql_query($query);
                        echo $result;
                        if ($result == FALSE) die ("could not execute statement $query<br />");
</php>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Checkboxes will appear in your `$_POST` array.

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Your inputs all need `name` attributes.

Comment: To reiterate the sentiment by @JayBlanchard - Do not use this code in any website that you care about.  It is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Use stored procedures in your DBMS whenever possible.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How can I $_POST with a 'Y' or 'N' result based on if it has been selected?

Comment: Add a value to each of your checkboxes. Unchecked checkboxes *do not appear* in the POST array.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks for your help! How do i then add this into my SQL statement?

Comment: You really do need to go take some basic PHP tutorials and work through them. The values of the checkboxes, being in the POST array, can then be used as variables in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to create a hidden lable. Check box does not post value if it is not selected. So you just need to check in php weather $_POST is set or not for example

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="proj_check" name="proj_check" value="Y"/>
 <input type="checkbox" id="white_check" name="white_check" value="Y"/>
```

and On php page you have to check like

```
if(isset($_POST['proj_check']))
   $proj_check = $_POST['proj_check'];
else
   $proj_check = "N";
```

then you can use $proj_check as per your need.